# Feed Forward Artificial Neural Network in PyBrain trains for Supervised Classification but does not predict

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pybrain, supervised-learning

I made a trainer which learns ok with acceptable error rate, but when I try to predict the classes on my trainer, it is not able to predict the classes.The code looks like this:

```
data = ClassificationDataSet(inpDim, 2, nb_classes=2)

for aSample in training_dataset:
    data.addSample((aSample[0:len(aSample)-1]),[aSample[len(aSample)-1]]);
```

## My data structure is like [1,......,311] = features where [311,..,312] = class labels

```
ann = buildNetwork(inpDim,2,outclass=SoftmaxLayer);
trainer = BackpropTrainer( ann, dataset=data, momentum=0.1, verbose=False, weightdecay=0.01)
trainer.trainEpochs(epoch);
```

I trained the network with 50 passes i.e 10 iterations with 5 epochs
It is giving a considerable training error but when I try to predict the classes , it is not predicting .

```
predictedLabel   = fann.testOnClassData(data) 
actualLabels = data['target']
precision_score(actualLabels,predictedLabel)
recall_score(actualLabels,predictedLabel)
```

When I call precision_score, it throws a warning saying no predicted samples.
I have two classes 0, 1 with 311 features and I am training my classifier with 500 + samples. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!